# Is it possible to have an entity kind with no property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to keep a list of 'things' in Datastore. No other information other than their names are required for these 'things', and these names must be unique, i.e. they can be thought as `key_name` for an entity. In this case, I don't need any explicit property/field for the entity kind (since the name of a 'thing' can be kept inside `key_name` of an entity). Is this possible? How? The alternative is to replicate this piece of information by having a dedicated field/property for name.

```
class EntityKindWithNoProperty(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
```

I feel like this approach is duplication of information. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works

```
class Empty(ndb.Model):
    pass

e = Empty(id="somestring")
e.put()
```

For uniqueness you can potentially generate the IDs in advance then consume them one by one with [numeric keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#numeric_keys). Or, depending on your use model, get_or_insert.

Comment: Is it intentional that you used `ndb`? Can the same thing be done with `db.Model`, and using `key_name` instead of `id`, e.g. `Empty.get_or_insert(key_name='something')`

Comment: Yes, I use NDB by default. Looking at the NDB cheat sheet https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic it seems that you can indeed use key_name as you suggest with get or insert.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having a single entity with a list property?

```
class ThingSingleton(db.Model):
    things = db.StringListProperty()
```

The best approach to use would depend on your query patterns and the expected cardinality of things.

Comment: The problem with this approach is Datastore contention. It is possible that the app will want to add a lot of items into `things` simultaneously. This would be really bad for performance.